# How to select codes with different sizes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python 3, with pandas, I have this dataframe with several codes in the columns "CPF_CNPJ_doador" and "CPF_CNPJ_doador_originario"

```
cand_doacoes = pd.read_csv("doacoes_csv.csv",sep=';',encoding = 'latin_1',  decimal = ",")

cand_doacoes.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 427489 entries, 0 to 427488
Data columns (total 12 columns):
UF                                427489 non-null object
Partido                           427489 non-null object
Cargo                             427489 non-null object
Nome_candidato                    427489 non-null object
CPF_candidato                     427489 non-null int64
CPF_CNPJ_doador                   426681 non-null float64
Nome_doador                       427489 non-null object
Nome_doador_Receita               427489 non-null object
Valor                             427489 non-null float64
CPF_CNPJ_doador_originario        427489 non-null object
Nome_doador_originario            427489 non-null object
Nome_doador_originario_Receita    427489 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(9)
memory usage: 39.1+ MB
```

The codes in the columns "CPF_CNPJ_doador" and "CPF_CNPJ_doador_originario" are always integers and of different sizes: 14 digits, 13 digits, 11 digits or 10 digits

Examples of codes in "CPF_CNPJ_doador": 1256007000131, 20566882000164, 11459125000109, 5746038000121...

I need to create a dataframe with only 14- and 13-digit codes. Please, does anyone know how I can select only the 14- and 13-digit codes in the "CPF_CNPJ_doador" column in the dataframe "cand_doacoes"? Do I need to convert to string first?

Comment: No add how `CPF_CNPJ_doador` looks like. seeing the datatype is not enough. We need to see data

Comment: Thanks, I put some examples above

Answer (score 3):

If you really have integers for the codes, one mathematical approach that should be quick is to take the base 10 log of the codes as integer type and add 1 to count the number of digits. This can be your mask.

```
np.isin(np.log10(df.code_column.values).astype(int) + 1, [13, 14])
```

For example (borrowing Bharath's data),

```
>>> df[np.isin(np.log10(df.num.values).astype(int) + 1, [13, 14])]
              num
0   1256007000131
1  20566882000164
2  11459125000109
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way using `astype(str).str.len()` and isin to select rows with only 13 and 14 digit values i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':[1256007000131, 20566882000164, 11459125000109, 57,5746038]})

df[df['num'].astype(str).str.len().isin([13,14])]
# Output 
              num
0   1256007000131
1  20566882000164
2  11459125000109
```

Answer (score 2):

borowing @Bharath's sample DF:

```
In [114]: df['num'].astype(str).str.match(r'\d{13,14}')
Out[114]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: num, dtype: bool

In [115]: df[df['num'].astype(str).str.match(r'\d{13,14}')]
Out[115]:
              num
0   1256007000131
1  20566882000164
2  11459125000109
```